# Import classes from folder

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and i want to import some classes to my application wich are placed in **MyClasses** folder in same package.

After googling for a time I found a way to do this by usig **Java build path** and  in this **add class folder**. I think this may solve my problem but no luck.

I don't know how to import classes from folders. Is it possible to import classes from folder? If it is possible then how to do this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to add classes or source files? Is the IDE Eclipse?

Comment: I am trying to add classes which are placed in MyClasses folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is for Eclipse. You have the options for importing a ***Class Folder***, which is not very useful in my opinion since it only loads folders in projects you have defined in your workspace. In this scenario I would just link to the project itself. But you can also import ***External Class Folders***. If this is what you are trying to accomplish then make sure you are using the correct item in the Java Build Path dialog.

[image]

Comment: yes you are right i am using eclipse and when i add class folder it only load folder in project.

Comment: Make sure you are picking the correct root folder. When selected, all further subfolder should form the natural package structure of the classes you are trying to import. So for example, you should just the root folder that contains `com`, for classes in packages `com.foo.whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that Dalvik does not understand java files. They should be compiled into the internal Dalvik format dex. And even after that I'm not sure that you can dynamically load files into your project.

Answer (score 0):

Have the folder in your build path, then use:

```
Class.forName("package.className")
```

It will also call the static constructor for the classes loaded this way (this pattern is used with JDBC drivers).

If you want to change the folder at runtime, you might have to write your own class loader.

This might help more: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/get-the-most-out-of-javas-class-loaders/6080883

Not sure how this works with Android, though. I don't think you can implement your own class loader for Android due to security issues.